# are there requirements for Struts setters beyond variable name matching?

Tags: struts2, struts, setter

I have a model-driven Struts Web action:

```
public class ModelDrivenAction<T extends Object> implements ModelDriven<T>, Preparable {

  protected Long id;
  protected T model;

  @Override
  public void prepare() {}

  public void setId(Long id) { this.id = id; }

  @Override
  public T getModel() { return model; }

  public void setModel(T model) { this.model = model; }
}
```

I have another action which is not currently model-driven:

```
public class OtherAction implements Preparable {

  private ModelObj modelObj;
  private Long modelId;

  @Override
  public void prepare() { modelObj = repoService.retrieveModelById(modelId); }

  public void setModelId(Long modelId) { this.modelId = modelId; }
}
```

I wish to make it so, and would like to avoid having to track down all the instances in JavaScript where the action is passed a "modelId" parameter instead of "id" if at all possible. I thought this might work, so either modelId or id could be passed in:

```
public class OtherAction extends ModelDrivenAction<ModelObj> {

  @Override
  public void prepare() { model = repoService.retrieveModelById(id); }

  public void setModelId(Long modelId) { this.id = modelId; }
}
```

However, `server/path/to/other!method?modelId=123` is failing to set id. I thought so long as a setter matched a parameter name the Struts interceptor would call it on action invocation. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Last i heard, there wasn't even a requirement that there *be* a backing field, much less that its name match up with its setter...what is this framework you're messing with that requires it?

Comment: @cHao: Isn't that the case for JavaBeans?

Comment: @Oli: Nope.  Beans require that your setters be named like `getFoo` and `setFoo`.  They don't require that there be a `private int foo` to match.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth it may/may not be the cause for JavaBeans but slk did not use the JavaBeans tag or otherwise specify it.  There are absolutely no requirements for java setters - because it is not a java concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The failure to set id was due to a misconfiguration in Eclipse; the code as listed above actually does do what I had hoped.